# Autofocus not working on chrome in angular 10

Tags: html, angular, voiceover, talkback, section508

I am trying to autofocus on to login id after incorrect login id and password message is displayed and announced on VOICE OVER/talk back.

It should shift focus to login id text field. to make sure my application **ADA and 508 Compliance**.

```
<input id="loginID" tabindex="0" autofocus matInput type="text" #userId placeholder="{{'LoginPage.UserID' | translate}}" ngModel
 formControlName="userId" required aria-required="true" aria-label="userId is mandatory field" aria-describedby="userIdValidationMsg">
```

Autofocus not working on chrome. Is there any suggestions to end up my search on this autofocus on google for angular 10.

> open for Suggestion on implementing the same solution in some other
> Approach.

Comment: Does the autofocus work before the incorrect login?

Comment: Does it work in any other browser?

Answer (score 0):

[`autofocus`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-autofocus-attribute) is typically used **on page load**.  In your case, it sounds like the page is already loaded, then the user types an incorrect login, and then you add `autofocus` dynamically?  If so, that's not the intended use of `autofocus`.  Instead, you can use javascript focus() on the `<input>`.

```
document.getElementById('loginID').focus();
```

Side note, you don't need `tabindex="0"` on the `<input>` because it's natively keyboard focusable.

Also, be careful if you have *both* an `aria-label` and a `<label>` element.  The `aria-label` will "win" and the `<label>` will be ignored.  Your code example doesn't show a `<label>` but *does* use `aria-label` so I wanted to mention it just in case.